# what is the best way to disable Input Text in Angular 15

Tags: html, angular, typescript, input, disable

I want to disable the Input box in Angular 15. I know I can use [disabled] attribute as below. The issue is, that the user can still right-click the control, view the source and remove the disabled attribute, making it enabled again.

```
<input  id="invoiceItem_qty" type="number"
                         class="form-control form-control-sm rounded-0"
                         [(ngModel)]="invoiceItem.qty"
                         name="invoiceItemQty"
                         #invoiceItemQty="ngModel" [disabled]="isLoading == true" />
```

Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: No matter what you do, a user will have developer tools and can modify client-side code. The only solution here is to validate the received data on the server-side of things since a user will never have access to that. For the reason you have stated here is why you can never 100% trust data from a client-side application.